# Change the @font-face of Arabic text

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, arabic

I am using `@font-face` to change the font style of Arabic text using the following CSS:

```
@font-face{
font-family:"HelveticaNeue";src:url(fonts/HelveticaNeueW23-Reg.eot);src:url(fonts/HelveticaNeueW23-Reg.woff)
format("woff"),url(fonts/HelveticaNeueW23-Reg.ttf)
format("truetype"),url(fonts/HelveticaNeueW23-Reg.svg#HelveticaNeueLTArabic55Roman)
format("svg");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal
}

@font-face{
font-family:"HelveticaNeue";src:url(fonts/HelveticaNeueW23-Bd.eot);src:url(fonts/HelveticaNeueW23-Bd.woff)
format("woff"),url(fonts/HelveticaNeueW23-Bd.ttf)
format("truetype"),url(fonts/HelveticaNeueW23-Bd.svg#HelveticaNeueLTArabic55Roman)
format("svg");font-weight:bold
}
```

But they do no effect! What is the problem? Do I need to use CSS3 or some Charset?

Comment: Where did you get this version web ready of Helvetica? are you sure it was encoded with the Arabic Character Set instead of the Western one?

Comment: yes I am sure this website vanoos.com is using the same code and same font

Comment: thanks, I should use font-family in replace of font

Comment: Cufon is a way you can use fonts like Helvetica in the web, search SO for it.